# Upload file dialog position

Tags: html, browser

Is there any way to set up position of the browser's upload file dialog (which is opened by pressing 'Browse' button of the  element)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, definitely not. This is outside of HTML's / Javascript's control.